# Деплой vue на сервер

Tags: vue.js, webpack

Помогите Разобраться. 
С помощью vue ui создал проект, после сборки как положено выдаёт папку dist, но index.html из нее запускается пустой.
Выкладываю на сервер - ситуация повторяется

Comment: Вы проверяли, что файлы действительно подключились? Если не подключились, то в инструментах разработчика будут соответствующие ошибки. Или какая нибудь другая ошибка будет. В chrome они открываются по f12.

Answer (score 1):

1. Проверьте, нет ли ошибок во время билда
2. Лично у меня index лежит в одной папки с dist, а не внутри нее. Может, в этом проблема?